# Organizing JavaScript code to be visible in Eclipse Outline

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsdt

How should I organize my JavaScript code to be visible well in deep in the Eclipse JSDT's Outline View?

For example, if I have a JS file containing the following content, Outline shows the one top level function only:

```
function topLevel() {
  var local1 = 1;
  var local2 = 2;
  function local() {};
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11062205/400925

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the web perspective in the "Open Perspective" dialog