# Enabling the JSDT Outline view in Eclipse Neon

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsdt

The question of the Outline view showing the contents of a JavaScript source file is not new and [it had even found an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11062205/2749913).

However, that answer no longer works in Neon (4.6.0): I have opened the exact same file of one project imported in two separate workspaces, one for each version of Eclipse, and Mars shows the complete outline (3 namespaces, about 80 members) whereas Neon shows two namespaces and 0 members. In the Java perspective.

For instance, the following code, taken from the question I've linked to above gives the following results in Mars SR2 and Neon:

```
var myNamespace = function()
{
    /**
     * @memberOf myNamespace
     */
    function myFunc1()
    {
    }
    /**
     * @memberOf myNamespace
     */
    function myFunc2()
    {
    }

    return {
        name : "myNamespace",
        myFunc1 : myFunc1,
        myFunc2 : myFunc2
    }
}();
```

Result in Mars SR2 (OK):

[image: Outline view in Eclipse Mars SR2]

Result in Neon (NOK):

[image: Outline view in Eclipse Neon]

Are there some new configuration settings that need to be enabled? The [JSDT Wiki at eclipse.org](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JSDT) is stark, the Help contents in Eclipse is not helpful at all and I have no idea where to find definitive instructions.

Visible spaces and the contents of the Outline view are things I cannot live without so I hope this is more a configuration thing than a bug.

[EDIT] **NOTE**: if you happen to use Mars with a later release and you have Oomph synchronization enabled, this outlining feature in Mars may disappear. It happened to me and the solution is to disable Oomph synchronization with later releases (Neon, in my case); I however continue to store the Mars preferences into the workspace (instead of having them saved into the user).

Comment: They say it is a feature not a bug "Outline tree nesting depth was limited to 1": https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472855, IMHO JSDT is ok for basic js development, but do not expect too much from it.

Comment: So it was limited to 1 on purpose... Not understandable to me but that's only my personal opinion. Anyway, since I can't develop without an Outline view (I wonder how people manage to code without one), I have moved on from JS in Eclipse because of the limitations in JSDT. I feel that the project is out of phase with my needs. I am now developing solely in TypeScript with Angelo Zerr's plugin. Many blessings on him.

Comment: Moving to TypeScript is a smart move in terms of IDE support it can easily get close to Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug was reported and fixed in [JSDT Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&list_id=15116059&product=JSDT&query_format=advanced). Please, check the specific bug page, where you can see how the developers collaborated to find a solution.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499788

Comment: Note: this bug has been fixed a few days after this question was asked and after @psuzzi reported the bug. The fix will be available in Neon.1 (to be released at the end of September 2016).

Comment: The wording of my previous comment is ambiguous and doesn't make the following clear: I'm not the one who fixed the bug :-)

Comment: I know who fixed the bug, I just wanted to add the bug is fixed !